# Properly mapping an xml schema in Excel

Tags: xml, excel

Long time reader, first time poster. It's time to mine this site for all it's knowledge!

I'm trying to set up an xml schema and populate the data inside excel. I've made some definitions for some complexTypes because they will be reused quite often. If I reference the type, for example 3 times, inside excel it only maps the type once.

I'm pretty new to schemas but my boss wants me to use them. Any other criticism would be greatly appreciated.

XML SCHEMA:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


<!-- Type Definitions (DoorStyle, Colour, Accessory and TamarackModel) -->

<xsd:complexType name="DoorStyle">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="style" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="wood" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="colour" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="imgsrc" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Colour">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="colour" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="wood" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="imgsrc" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Accessory">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="pdf" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="TamarackModel">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="drawing" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="reverseDrawing" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="priceSheet" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<!-- Group Definitions (DoorStyles, Colours, Accessories and TamarackModels) -->

<xsd:element name="DoorStyles">
  <xsd:complexType>
<!-- <xsd:attribute name="url" type="xsd:string" fixed="http://www.muskokacabco.com/muskoka-kitchens-gallery-door-styles.html"/> -->
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="DoorStyle" type="DoorStyle"/>
      <xsd:element name="DoorStyle" type="DoorStyle"/>
      <xsd:element name="DoorStyle" type="DoorStyle"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="Colours">
  <xsd:complexType>
<!-- xsd:attribute name="url" type="xsd:string" fixed="http://www.muskokacabco.com/muskoka-kitchens-gallery-stain-colours.html"/> -->
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Colour" type="Colour"/>
      <xsd:element name="Colour" type="Colour"/>
      <xsd:element name="Colour" type="Colour"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="Accessories">
  <xsd:complexType>
<!-- <xsd:attribute name="url" type="xsd:string" fixed="http://www.muskokacabco.com/muskoka-kitchens-accessories.html"/> -->
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Accessory" type="Accessory"/>
      <xsd:element name="Accessory" type="Accessory"/>
      <xsd:element name="Accessory" type="Accessory"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="TamarackModels">
  <xsd:complexType>
<!-- <xsd:attribute name="url" type="xsd:string" fixed="http://www.muskokacabco.com/muskoka-kitchens-tamarack-models.html"/> -->
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="TamarackModel" type="TamarackModel"/>
      <xsd:element name="TamarackModel" type="TamarackModel"/>
      <xsd:element name="TamarackModel" type="TamarackModel"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>


<!-- Overall Structure -->

<xsd:element name="MuskokaSite">
<!-- <xsd:attribute name="url" type="xsd:string" fixed="http://www.muskokacabco.com"/> -->
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="DoorStyles"/>
      <xsd:element ref="Colours"/>
      <xsd:element ref="Accessories"/>
      <xsd:element ref="TamarackModels"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

So I reference each type about 3 times, but in excel it only lets me map each type once if I choose  as root. I would have loved to include a screenshot but apparently new users can't do that...

Comment: What is the question?  How does any of this relate to Excel? Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for posting guidelines.

Comment: I am importing an XSD Schema to excel, then exporting to xml. The question was how to have more than one reference to an element. I'd post the fix but StackOverflow is apparently very limiting to newbies. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the "maxOccurs" attribute on elements defaults to one. I set it to "unbounded" and it works now.

```
    <xsd:group name="DoorStyles">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="DoorStyle" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:group>
```